# A really harsh short puzzle

Tags: wordplay, computer-puzzle

I may be burned at the stake for this one so "sorry" in advance!

> When does pot and top make it without a why?

(You may need a particular object to figure this one out...)

Hint

> As revealed in comments below, a qwerty keyboard/pad of a sort will help to find the answer.

Hint #2:

> One key higher...

Comment: Harsh? This is a no-brainer!

Comment: 09234 59 697!!!

Comment: @Strawberry it was harsh before the hints...

Comment: @Tom Nice one :P +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at

> Hint 2

It seems as though

> Each letter corresponds to the key to the left diagonally above it

Then

> top $\rightarrow$ 590 
>   pot $\rightarrow$ 095 and 
>  590 + 095 = 685 $\leftarrow$ yit = 'y' + 'it'. 
>  So adding 'top' and 'pot' makes 'yit' which, without the 'y', is 'it'.

Comment: Well done, and well explained as always. +1  This gets even easier if you're looking at a typical smartphone keyboard.  I didn't expect anyone to get it right away until I got the hints.

Comment: 630 697 4 599 43234853 85 one key higher.

Answer (score 1):

I opt for

> a **typo** which you could misspell as pot or top without y   
>  The object may be a keyboard - and o and p are adjacent

Comment: You're close with the keyboard and maybe the typo thing but it's not about spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Try number 2... and if I get it... it's because @Tom led the way...

> Dvorak keyboard layout, on QWRTY T-O-P and P-O-T are on the same row as Y, however on Dvorak layout you would never cross Y to get T to O to P or visa versa... [image: Dvorak layout with path TOP and POT shown][image]

Comment: Sorry.  That's not it at all.  Only qwerty layout is involved.  Could have made a bloody good puzzle with that though.

Answer (score 1):

Current thoughts:

> On a QWERTY keyboard, to make top in a direct path, one must pass through TYUIOP, of which I and T make 'it', and vice versa. So, big. Question is, how do we plot a path to make TOP and POT, making 'IT' in the process without crossing Y?

Comment: Nice to see the thought process +1 but the puzzle wasn't so much about plotting paths.  I see where you were coming from though considering some of the other puzzles I've seen here.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit off... but this is what I came up with:

ANSWER:

> MORTAR 
> a **martyr** is someone who is killed because of their beliefs. 
> you mentioned 'being burned at the stake'
> Without the 'Y'martyr becomes martr add 'top' and unscramble, you have mortar,
>  parrot, and raptor...
> I chose mortar because it would be the one of the options that would require
> an object (brick or stone) to give it meaning outside of the riddle...

Comment: Sorry, I've added some formatting for a bit of clarity.  The puzzle is only the indented part.